# Angularfire AGM need to display multiple markers

Tags: angular, angularfire

I want to show multiple markers on AGM map realtime this code is working for only one marker. I have just stated learning to code so... and also recommend me a tutorial to learn angular.

App Component:

```
constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase){
    this.data = db.object('/raw-locations/8290/0').valueChanges();
}
```

App Html:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="31.5718289" [longitude]="74.3690473">
    <agm-marker *ngIf="data"
        [latitude]="(data |async)?.lat"
        [longitude]="(data | async)?.lng"
        [label]="Stickcar"
        zoom="4"
        [iconUrl]="ico"
        [label]="label">

        <agm-info-window>{{ label }}</agm-info-window>
    </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

[app commonent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w78VJ.png)

[app html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHs88.png)

[database stucture on firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYSWs.png)

Comment: Posting images of your code is not helpful. It takes longer for you to post your code and users can't copy and paste it to try and recreate your issue.

Comment: ok i am uploading the files

Comment: Don't upload them either, simply copy and paste the relevant parts of the code into the question body, then highlight the code and press the code button (`{ }`) to indent them.

Comment: Or just use something like jsfiddle, so everyone can run and play with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array with all your markers parameters (latitude, longitude, label, iconUrl, etc.) in your .ts file and then use *ngFor to iterate over all of them:

App Component;

```
constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase){
        this.locations = //Get all your markers
}
```

App HTML:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="31.5718289" [longitude]="74.3690473">
    <agm-marker 
       *ngFor="let marker of locations"
        [latitude]="(marker |async)?.lat"
        [longitude]="(marker | async)?.lng"
        [label]="marker.label"
        zoom="4"
        [iconUrl]="marker.ico"
        [label]="marker.label">

        <agm-info-window>{{ label }}</agm-info-window>
    </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```